# How to exchange integration and summation operator in Maple?

Tags: maple

I want to integrate a function expanded by a series as below:

```
Eq1:=int(x*f(x),x);
subs(f(x) = sum(l[i](x)*f(x[i]), i = 0 .. n), Eq1);
```

Then I want to do the integration first, followed by summation, is there any Maple command to do that?

```
'sum(f(x[i])*int(l[i](x)*x, x), i = 0 .. n)';
```

[image]

I want to exchange the calculation procedure of integration and summation in Maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's construct a procedure that will turn an integral of a sum into a sum of an integral.

```
G := proc(IS) local ig;
  uses IntegrationTools;
  ig := GetIntegrand(IS);
  op(0,ig)(op(0,IS)(op(1,ig),op(2..,IS)),
                    op(2..,ig));
end proc:
```

Now, your example.

It's a very bad idea to use indexed names `x[i]` within an integral whose variable-of-integration is `x`. I've changed `x[i]` to `X[i]`.

```
Eq1 := int(x*f(x),x):
new := subs(f(x) = sum(l[i](x)*f(X[i]), i = 0 .. n),
            Eq1);

     int(x*sum(l[i](x)*f(X[i]),i = 0 .. n),x)
```

Bring the factor `x` inside the sum, to get
that form of an integral of a sum.

```
temp := combine(new);

     int(sum(x*l[i](x)*f(X[i]),i = 0 .. n),x)
```

Now apply G to it,

```
ans := G(temp);

     sum(int(x*l[i](x)*f(X[i]),x),i = 0 .. n)
```

You may prefer that the factor `f(X[i])` is outside the integral.

```
IntegrationTools:-Expand(ans);

     sum(f(X[i])*int(x*l[i](x),x),i = 0 .. n)
```

The procedure `G` is re-usable. We can now easily apply it to any subexpression (of a larger expression) that is of the form of an integral of a sum.

This works whether we have "active" `int` and `sum` or inert `Int` and `Sum`. It also preserves any extra arguments, and handles definite as well as indefinite integrals.

```
Eq2 := 1/Int(x*g(x),x=a..b) + foo + int(x*f(x),x);

new2 := subs(f(x) = sum(l[i](x)*f(X[i]), i = 0 .. n),
             g(x) = Sum(l[i](x)*g(X[i]), i = 0 .. n),
             Eq2):

temp2 := subsindets(new2,specfunc({int,Int}),combine):
```

Apply G to any subexpression that is an integral of a sum.

```
ans2 := subsindets(temp2,
                   And(specfunc({int,Int}),
                       satisfies(u->type(op(1,u),
                         specfunc({sum,Sum})))),
                   G);

    1/Sum(Int(x*l[i](x)*g(X[i]),x = a .. b),i = 0 .. n)
    + foo
    + sum(int(x*l[i](x)*f(X[i]),x),i = 0 .. n)
```

Bring the factors `g(X[i])` and `f(X[i])` outside the integrals.

```
IntegrationTools:-Expand(ans2);

    1/Sum(g(X[i])*Int(x*l[i](x),x = a .. b),i = 0 .. n)
    + foo
    + sum(f(X[i])*int(x*l[i](x),x),i = 0 .. n)
```